# Passing GET parameters to Express+Mongoose Restful API

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm just getting into Node, Express, and Mongoose. Loving it so far, but can't figure out how to pass MongoDB filtering from the AJAX call to the API.

I have a simple jQuery AJAX request like this:

```
$.getJSON('/api/products', {
    filter: { status: 'active' } // <-- Want this to get processed by the API
}, function(products){
    console.log(products);
});
```

Here are the important parts of my Express + Mongoose API:

```
// Define Mongoose Schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Product Schema
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: 'string', required: false },
    price: { type: 'number', required: false },
    status: { type: 'string', required: false },
    description: { type: 'string', required: false },
});

// Product Model
var ProductModel = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

// Product Endpoint
app.get('/api/products', function(req, res){
    return ProductModel.find(function(error, products){
        return res.send(products);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be sending the encoded paramters with your request as it is. Now you just need to get them and pass it to your query:

```
// Product Endpoint
app.get('/api/products', function(req, res){

    var filter =  {};
    for ( var k in req.query.filter ) {
        filter[k] = req.query.filter[k];   // probably want to check in the loop
    }
    return ProductModel.find(filter, function(error, products){
        return res.send(products);
    });
});
```

That loop is there because you might want to check what was sent in. But I'll leave that up to you.

Also `req.params` if that suits your taste.